# Chrome.extension.sendMessage within chrome.tabs.create

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, sendmessage

I need to create a chrome extension which captures the current visible tab and open it in a new tab. I use the following code:

**send.js**

```
    function openNextPage(imagesrc) {  
   chrome.tabs.create({url: "newScreen.html"},function(tab){  
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({someParam: imagesrc},function(response){console.log(response);});
    }  
  );    
}
```

And inside **newScreen.html** I had included **receive.js** as follows:

```
window.addEventListener("load",function(){
    console.log('contents Loaded');
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request,sender,response) {
        console.log(request.someParam);
    });
});
```

The problem is, once the new tab is created(first **newScreen.html** ) I could see **Contents Loaded** message, but not the **imagesrc**. Maybe because the onMessage.addEventListener is executed later(after sendMessage).

But if I click my extension again and it opens the 2nd **newScreen.html** , the previous **newScreen.html** receives the message and prints it. If I open a third tab, the first and second tabs are receiving the message again. The problem is sendMessage executes even before onMessageListener is added. I used TimeOut for sendMessage but in vain. Help me out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're saying

> Maybe because the `onMessage.addEventListener` is executed later (after `sendMessage`).

And yes, that's true: you're using the `window.onload` listener to wait until the window loads, but **the message is sent before the window loads completely**. You should place your `chrome.runtime.onMessage` listener out of the `window.onload` listener, like this:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request,sender,response) {
    console.log(request.someParam);
});

window.addEventListener("load",function(){
    console.log('contents Loaded');
});
```

If you want, you can store the request in some global variable, so that you can use it inside the `window.onload` event handler and make sure all the work is done when the window has been loaded, like this:

```
var MY_PARAMETER;
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request,sender,response) {
    MY_PARAMETER = request.someParam;
});

window.addEventListener("load",function(){
    // Now you are sure that the window is loaded
    // and you can use the MY_PARAMETER variable
    console.log("Contents loaded, MY_PARAMETER =", MY_PARAMETER);
});
```

Obviously, you'll need to put this `receive.js` script on top of your markup, inside the `<head>` of the document, to make sure that the listener is added as soon as it can:

```
<html>
    <head>
        ...
        <script src="/path/to/request.js"></script>
        ...
    </head>
...
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked.. :) i was trying every possible event and finally this worked!